# Class "row" in Bootstrap makes pull right even more

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

Suppose I have the following Bootstrap pagination inside container:

```
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If I wrap the above code in `<div class="row"> ... </div>` the pagination pulls right even more causing misalignment with the table that goes above it. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `.row` has a left and right margin of -15px.

You should be adding a `.col-xx-xx`, which counteracts the negative margins using padding, as the child of `.row`.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-groups pull-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="i in range(tiGroupsData.total_pages) track by $index"><a href="#">{{$index+1}}</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Even if I use it inside container?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Read the [Grid System - Introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) in the Bootstrap Documentation.